Is there a relation between Fubini's theorem and change of variable theorem?
In an exercise, it asks to use the change of variable theorem to calculate a double integral, but then it asks to redo the work using Fubini's theorem. Is there a way to benefit from previous work? In the solution, the teacher directly writes the transformed old domain, which is similar to that of the change of variable with some modifications. So, is there a way to switch between the two methods?
This is the domain:
$ D = \{(x, y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 \mid 2 = y < x < 2y \text{ and } y < x^2 < 2y\} $
And this is the change of variable demand:
$ u = \frac{y}{x}, \quad v = \frac{x^2}{y} $
This is my work with the method of change variable:
\begin{cases}
y < x < 2y \\
y < x^2 < 2y
\end{cases}
\begin{cases}
u < 1 < 2u \\
1 < v < 2
\end{cases};
\begin{cases}
\frac{1}{2} < u < 1 \\
1 < v < 2
\end{cases};
And I calculate the area, but when I try to apply Fubini's theorem, I really face problems finding the domain. When I see the solution, I find that the teacher writes directly:
\begin{align*}
D_1 &= \{(x, y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 \ \frac{1}{2} < x < 1 \text{ and } x^2 < y < x^2\} \\
D_2 &= \{(x, y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 \ 1 < x < 2 \text{ and } x^2 < y < x\}
\end{align*}
And I can't understand why and how

What does $2=1$ in your last equation mean?

sorry, it is just a mistake n latex code

As its always a good idea to have a look at the geometry
  RegionPlot[{ y < x < 2 y && y < x^2 < 2 y}, {x, 0, 2}, {y, 0, 2}]


Solve for the direct transform indicated
 map=Solve[{u == y/x, v == x^2/y}, {x, y}]

$$map=\left\{x\to u v,y\to u^2 v\right\}$$
Convert integrand time $\mathit{dx} \wedge  \mathit{dy}$ by exterior diffentiation
$$\mathit{dx}\wedge \mathit{dy}=\left(2 \mathit{du}\  u\  v+\mathit{dv} \ u^2\right) \wedge (\mathit{du} \ v+\mathit{dv} \ u) =\left(u^2 v-2 u^2 v\right) \ \mathit{du}\wedge \mathit{dv}$$
Get the boundaries
  { y < x < 2 y && y < x^2 < 2 y} /. {x -> u v, y -> u^2 v}  = 
  {1/2 < u < 1 && 1 < v < 2}

By Fubini, the nested integrals yield
$$\int_{\frac{1}{2}}^1 \left(\int_1^2 \left(u^2 v-2 u^2 v\right) \, dv\right) \, du=-\frac{7}{16}$$
independent of the order of integration with partial integrals
$$\int_1^2 \left(u^2 v-2 u^2 v\right) \, dv=-\frac{1}{2} \left(3 u^2\right) , \qquad \int_{\frac{1}{2}}^1 \left(u^2 v-2 u^2 v\right) \, du=-\frac{1}{24} (7 v)$$

$-7/16,?$ A negative area? (The good news is that the numerical value agrees with the $0.4375$ I got.)

All areas are signed, all edges are signed, too, thats the essential of exterior calculus and the method to patch areas together such that all inner line integrals cancel and Stokes theorem works even for the blind. The overall sign is positive, if the boundary integral circles arround the area against the clock sense, as dictated by the Riemann integral, whose Stokes starts along the x-axis and follows the contour of f(x) from left to right.

You don't have to teach me the Stokes theorem. Integrating counterclockwise $$
\int_{\partial S^1}-y,dx+x,dy=\int_0^{2\pi}\sin^2\theta+\cos^2\theta,d\theta=2\pi
$$ gives two times the positive area of the unit disk, as it should because the curl of the vector field  $(-y,x,0)$ is $(0,0,2),.$

Too long for a comment.

Your notation
$$
D=\Big\{(x,y)\in\mathbb R^2\,\Big|\,\color{red}{2=y}<x<2y\quad\text{ and }\quad y<x^2<2y\Big\} 
$$
is nonsense. It seems what you mean is
$$
D=\Big\{(x,y)\in\mathbb R^2\,\Big|\;y\in[0,2]\;\text{ and }\;y<x<2y\;\text{ and }\; y<x^2<2y\Big\}\,. 
$$

It also helps to plot that region in Desmos which shows that the area of $D$ is


\begin{align}
\int_D\,dx\,dy&=\int_\tfrac14^\tfrac12\int_{\sqrt{y}}^{2y}\,dx\,dy
+\int_\tfrac12^1\int_{\sqrt{y}}^{\sqrt{2y}}\,dx\,dy
+\int_1^2\int_y^{\sqrt{2y}}\,dx\,dy\\[2mm]
&=\int_\tfrac14^\frac122y-\sqrt{y}\,dy+\int_\tfrac12^1\sqrt{2y}-\sqrt{y}\,dy
+\int_1^2\sqrt{2y}-y\,dy\\[2mm]
&=\tfrac1{48} (13 - 8 \sqrt2)+\tfrac5{3\sqrt{2}} - 1+\tfrac16 (7 - 4 \sqrt{2})\\[2mm]
&\approx 0.4375\,.
\end{align}

You can now use other integration techniques (Fubini, change of variables)
to arrive at the same result.

